# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
 const unbanUserId = interaction.options.getString('user_id')

  try {
      const getGuildBanList = await interaction.guild.bans.fetch()
      const checkTheUserStated = getGuildBanList.get(unbanUserId).user

    if (checkTheUserStated) {
       await interaction.guild.members.unban(unbanUserId)
        const unBannedEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('PURPLE')
        .setTitle('User unbanned')
        .setDescription(`Successfully unbanned <@!${unbanUserId}>`)

        return interaction.editReply({ embeds: [unBannedEmbed] })
    } else {
        const notBanned = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('PURPLE')
        .setDescription(`The stated user is not banned.`)

        return interaction.editReply({ embeds: [notBanned] })
    }
  } catch(e) {
      console.log(e)
  }
```

I am trying to make it so that when the user isn't banned that it will return a simple embed but it seem just too keep returning `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')`

Comment: what if you `console.log( getGuildBanList );` before creating `const checkTheUserStated`  Does it return an array of users?  Is the `await` necessary?  Is all of this code inside an async function?

Comment: Yes its all inside an async function.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using `.find()` ?

```js
const checkTheUserStated = getGuildBanList.find(user => user.id === unbanUserId.id);
```

console.log it or try it out, let me know if it works out for you

Comment: Great, I checked this out and it worked.

Comment: Okay perfect, can you add it as the right answer ? It helps other users searching for the same issue